# loading custom image on mkmaps

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mapkit

I want to develop a mall navigator however i am unsure where to start. I want to create something similar to this screenshot - http://navigationapps.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/point-inside-2.png . I believe its a custom loaded map with a pin tracker on it however how can i do this? (are there any tutorials/examples i could look at?). Furthermore, assuming that the mall has a clear signal, how accurate will the tracking be - within how many meters?). Would appreciate some help on this. Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Recently I had to develop an app using [`MKMapView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapView_Class/MKMapView/MKMapView.html) using custom callouts (annotations). You won't get around subclassing `MKAnnotationView` if you want to do a lot of customizations to it.

What helped me most were those tutorials:

**Intro Tutorial**: http://mithin.in/2009/06/22/using-iphone-sdk-mapkit-framework-a-tutorial

**Part 1**: http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-1/

**Part 2**: http://blog.asolutions.com/2010/09/building-custom-map-annotation-callouts-part-2/ (Also handles buttons inside your callout)

Answer (score 0):

I believe, You need tiles overlay.

Have a look at:

https://github.com/mtigas/iOS-MapLayerDemo

https://github.com/route-me/route-me