# display user location upon viewDidAppear

Tags: iphone, annotations, mapkit, android-mapview

I am trying to add an annotation to the user's current location upon loading the view. How Should I go about doing so? It would be good if there's examples as I am new.

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

As of displaying the current location as an annotation I did the following:

```
    // Set up the annotation
LocationAnnotation *annotation = [[LocationAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:[numberFormatter numberFromString:[[location valueForKey:@"latitude"] description]] andLongitude:[numberFormatter numberFromString:[[location valueForKey:@"longitude"] description]] andTitle:[location valueForKey:@"name"] andSubtitle:[location valueForKey:@"notes"]];
[numberFormatter release];

[self.mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
```

The Annotation header class looks like this:

```
@interface LocationAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

UIImage *image;
NSNumber *latitude;
NSNumber *longitude;
NSString *locationTitle;
NSString *locationSubtitle;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *latitude;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *longitude;

@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *locationTitle;
@property(nonatomic,retain) NSString *locationSubtitle;

-(id)initWithLatitude:(NSNumber *)aLatitude andLongitude:(NSNumber *)aLongitude andTitle:(NSString *)aLocationTitle andSubtitle:(NSString *)aLocationSubtitle;

@end
```

The `addAnnotation` method and `MKAnnotation` Protocol is what you're looking for to accomplish this.

If you want to show custom locations, you won't come around creating your own `MKAnnotation` as mentioned here:

[loading custom image on mkmaps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7030998/loading-custom-image-on-mkmaps/7031165#7031165)

Comment: I know of this, but that's not I wanted. I wanna add my own annotation to it.

Comment: How can I go about getting the user's current latitude and longitude upon viewDidAppear?

Comment: You can get the current coordinate by the `CLLocationManager`'s `coordinate` property - see : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007126

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you set the `showsUserLocation` property of your `MKMapView` to `YES`.

This property only **enables** the display of the user location.